# Why i am getting textFormField multiline error?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                      maxLines: 4,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: AppColors.ARGB.withOpacity(0.3),
                        isDense: true,
                        focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                        )),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                              DimensionsResource.RADIUS_EXTRA_SMALL),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                        ),
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 16, bottom: 16, left: 10),
                        hintText: 'Enter Detected Box IDs',
                        hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                          color: AppColors.WHITE,
                          fontSize: DimensionsResource.FONT_SIZE_SMALL_2X,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

> Obscured fields cannot be multiline. Failed assertion: line 171 pos
> 15: '!obscureText || maxLines == 1'

getting this error

Comment: Seems like issue is another place. This provide code has no issue.

Comment: Obscured fields used for the password field. There is no reason to have a multiline password field. Here is the official PR about it : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/42470

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is due to the combination of the `obscureText` property set to `true` and the `maxLines` property set to a value greater than `1`. The `obscureText` property is used to hide the text input as it is being typed, and it is not compatible with multiline text fields.

To resolve this error, you have two options:

1. Set `obscureText` to `false` if you want a multiline text field. This will allow users to see the text as they type it, but it will not be hidden.
2. Set `maxLines` to `1` if you want to keep the text field obscured. This will prevent users from entering multiple lines of text, but it will also keep the text hidden.

Here's a breakdown of the error message:

Obscured fields cannot be multiline. Failed assertion: line 171 pos 15: `'!obscureText || maxLines == 1'`

- "Obscured fields cannot be multiline" indicates that the combination of `obscureText` being `true` and `maxLines` being greater than `1` is not allowed.
- "Failed assertion: line 171 pos 15: '`!obscureText || maxLines == 1`'" refers to the specific line of code (line 171) where the assertion is failing. The assertion checks whether `!obscureText || maxLines == 1`, which means that either `obscureText` should be `false` or maxLines should be `1`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: i tried to set obsecrue text property to false...but still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this code:

```
TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        filled: true,
        fillColor: AppColors.ARGB.withOpacity(0.3),
        isDense: true,
        focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
          width: 1,
        )),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
              DimensionsResource.RADIUS_EXTRA_SMALL),
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
        ),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 16, bottom: 16, left: 10),
        hintText: 'Enter Detected Box IDs',
        hintStyle: const TextStyle(
          color: AppColors.WHITE,
          fontSize: DimensionsResource.FONT_SIZE_SMALL_2X,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```